# Symfony form validation.

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm just a beginner with Symfony.

Here is my Member Entity with field "login".

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="login", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $login;
```

}

In the controller I call

function addAction(Request $request){
 $member = new Member();

```
    $formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $member);

    // We add required fields
   $formBuilder ->add('login','text', 'required' => true)
```

}

Does the form check the required of the login field when I call 
 // We verify if the form is valid
        if ($form->isValid()) { }

Answer (score 2):

`Required` only adds the input attribute `required="required"` to the html and is not a validation.

For more infos on actual form validation check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Yours would be the `NotNull` or `NotBlank` validation

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraint when building form field. Try this:

```
$formBuilder -> add('login','text', array(
     'constraints' => new NotBlank())
);
```

More info you can find at http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/introduction.html#form-validation